# mobile navbar resizes on changing text of an item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar with two items in a jquery mobile site:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:audioPause();" id="play-btn">Pause</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:audioStop();" id="stop-btn">Stop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I change the text of the links, with `$('#play-btn').text('Play');` its size changes, so that navbar item height is only that of the text. So after changing the text of #play-btn I end up with

```
+--------+--------+
| play   |  stop  |
+--------|        |
         +--------+
```

How can I get round this? (I thought maybe I need to tell the navbar to draw itself again somehow, but don't know how.)

Thanks.

Comment: The real question is - why is it higher than normal originally?

Comment: @liho1eye The navbar is standard height and has some padding around the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the structure of a button after jQuery Mobile has initialized it. To change the text you want to target the element with the `.ui-btn-text` class:

```
$('#play-btn').find('.ui-btn-text').text('Play');
```

This will keep all the proper formatting. Your current code is overwriting the HTML structure of the button.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4NDcn/1/ (Notice I attached `click` event handlers without using the `href` attribute)

Here is the structure of a button for jQuery Mobile 1.0:

```
<a id="play-btn" href="#" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-active">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Pause</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say something similar. Give your navbar a class, like class="navbar", and then in your CSS you can specify a height for your navbar.

```
.navbar{
        height:40px;display:block;
       }
```

See if that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather rely on the mobile ui to decide how big a navbar should be on a particular device etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text more concisely:

```
$('#play-btn .ui-btn-text').text('Play');
```